# KNET KTAP integration with my NFC enabled Android POS to accept payments

Tags: android, flutter, nfc, payment

How can we integrate KTAP of KNET to accept payments from customer? I need to integrate with my Android device which has NFC.

How to integrate KTAP with NFC enabled android device to accept payments in Kuwait. KTAP is the service provided by the KNET to make payments by taping NFC devices without security PIN

Answer (score 0):

Your question has multiple layers.

1. You can scan NFC Cards with the normal Android API for scanning NFC Tags. Those will create NDEF Data and make it so that you can read data from the TAG. This is the same with payment cards even though they might use some sort of encryption to make the data not accessible to thiefs.
2. Mobile Card Payment works with different techniques. One way is to use the Card as an "Auth Token" for the Payment and make it the "authority" that signs the payment. Antoher way is to just use the card as an identifier and make the user accept the payment on the vendor side.
3. Form a developing perspective you have mulitple possibilites regarding your concern: (difficult) You can basically set up a bank infrastructure and process the payment yourself. This is a dissicult way due to significant regulatory problems and hurdles. The signifcantly easyier way is to just use a payment provider. If you cooperate with Visa/Mastercard/Paypal/Google Wallet etc. you have simple API calls that authorize the user and can be made to pass your payment. I would then make it so that the user has to log in with his/her bank details and you just use the SEPA bank invoice to get your  money.